# Modificar las etiquetas del eje Y en plt.barh

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datos

Tengo un dataframe con varias columnas, supongamos A, B, C, D y E. A partir de este dataframe hago un grafico plt.barh donde empleo la columna A como eje Y y la columna B como eje X. Las etiquetas para los valores en el eje Y seran los contenidos en la columna A. Sin embargo, necesito que en esas etiquedas aparezca el texto de la columna A, y entre parentesis el de la columna E. No tengo nada claro como incluir la informacion de mas de una columna en el texto de la etiqueta.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner (como texto) un extracto de tu dataframe para que la respuesta pueda incluir código funcional que realmente genere un resultado sobre unos datos? Preferiblemente incluye también el fragmento de código que tienes ahora mismo para que la respuesta no tenga que partir de cero.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.barh(df_anomalies["title"], df_anomalies["revenue"])

plt.show()
```

Es un grafico de barras horizontales en base al dataframe "df_anomalies". Este tiene 3 columnas de interes: "revenue", "title", y "year". El eje Y de la grafica corresponde a la columna "title", de manera que en las etiquetas aparecen los titulos. Pero ademas de eso, quiero que aparezcan en las etiquetas del eje Y, entre parentesis, los datos de la columna "year", que indican el año de salida de ese titulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el grafico resultante. Y donde aparece por ejemplo "Bambi", me gustaria que apareciese entre parentesis el año de la pelicula (por ejemplo "(1970)", que es un dato almacenado en la columna "year" del dataframe.